# How to show Call History by Q - municate?

Tags: objective-c, messaging, whatsapp, quickblox, q-municate

I am using Q-municate for chatting, audio and video calling feature in my application. I want to show call history (Incoming, outgoing , call time etc) like WhatsApp . Please guide me if anybody knows how I can implement this or provide a sample for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The call history option is absent in Q-municate, but you can implement this option with the help of Custom Objects.

You can collect notifications from the chat about the start/end of the call to create call history.

QB Custom Objects documentation:

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios

https://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects